# How many solutions have: $|X_1|+ \ldots +|X_n| = k$

Tags: combinatorics

$k$,$n$ are both Natural numbers, $k\geq n$

$X_1,\cdots ,X_n$ are Integers. 
$|X_i|\geq 1$.

I have to find how many solutions have   $|X_1|+\dots+|X_n|=k$.

I started with:

$|X_1+\cdots +X_n|\leq|X_1|+\cdots +|X_n|=k$

$|X_1+\cdots +X_n|+X_n+1=k$

But I'm not sure how to continue. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Assume, first, that all of them are positive, then is a stars and bars argument that gives $\binom{k-1}{n-1}$(Do you see how?) now, as there is no difference in between choosing negative or positive numbers, you have $2$ choices for each summand, and hence there should be $\binom{k-1}{n-1}2^n$ of those solutions.

Comment: why it is stars and bars argument ? and why there is no difference in between choosing negative or positive numbers? @Phicar

Comment: Hi, to answer the first question, take $k$ and write it as $k$ ones, as an example $k=5=1+1+1+1+1,$ you need to separe them in $n=3$ summands, hence you have to choose $2$ of those $+$ and then you get a partition. It does not matter possitive or negative because they are inside an absolute value.